# Angular http.get not getting data

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I have a simple Rails5 API and I'm trying to get data from the API in my Angular application.

First of, if I visit: http://localhost:3000/movies I get this result:

> [{"id":2,"title":"Batman","created_by":"1","created_at":"2017-06-17T07:19:35.000Z","updated_at":"2017-06-17T07:19:35.000Z"}]

So the Rails side works.

In my `app.component.ts` I import:

```
import { AppService }         from "./app.service";
import { Movie }              from './movie';
```

movie.ts

```
export class Movie{
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

app.service.ts

import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response }       from '@angular/http';

```
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Movie }                from './movie';

@Injectable()
export class AppService{

  private moviesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/movies';

  constructor(private http: Http){

  }

  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.moviesUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response){
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

And finally my `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';
import { AppService }         from "./app.service";
import { Movie }              from './movie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AppService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  errorMessage: string;
  movies: Movie[];
  mode = 'Observable';

  constructor(private  appService: AppService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getMovies();
    console.log(this.movies);
  }

  getMovies(){
    this.appService.getMovies()
      .subscribe(
        movies => this.movies = movies,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

When I visit `http://localhost:3000/movies` in my browser I get the following in my Puma log:

> Started GET "/movies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-17 10:35:00 +0200
>   Processing by MoviesController#index as HTML
>     Movie Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `movies`.* FROM `movies`
>   Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

When I visit http://localhost:4200/ where my Angular application is I get

> Started GET "/movies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-17 10:37:59 +0200
>   Processing by MoviesController#index as HTML
>     Movie Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `movies`.* FROM `movies`
>   Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

So the Angular application does the request to the API and the API returns the result but that result does not show up in the Angular component.

Comment: You are not getting any data in `console.log(this.movies)` called in the `ngOnInit()`, right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: @Abrar correct. So yes, maybe the http.get does receive data but doesn't Angular first do the `this.getMovies` function and when that is complete the `console.log` in ngOnInit?

Comment: the console.log method will be executed independent of the http request is completed or not. You should move that inside of the subscribe method, in the success case

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, take a look at the answer I gave below

Answer (score 0):

In Angular we use `Observable`, which you import from `rxjs/Observable`, to handle asynchronous code.

Notice here that when you call `this.appService.getMovies()` which returns an `Observable<Movie[]>`, this is essentially an asynchronous operation. In the `AppComponent` you `subscribe` to it and get the value **Asynchrously**.

Notice the `AppComponent` code -

```
 export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  errorMessage: string;
  movies: Movie[];
  mode = 'Observable';

  constructor(private  appService: AppService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getMovies();
    console.log(this.movies); <--- the value is not set to this.movies yet since data is loading asynchronously 
  }

  getMovies(){
    this.appService.getMovies()
      .subscribe(
        (movies) => {
              this.movies = movies;
              console.log(this.movies);  <--- the value will be set here properly
        },

        (error) => {
              this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EXTRA**

For more reading on **Observable**

- https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html
- https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-introduction-to-reactive-extensions-rxjs-a86a7430a61f

Comment: An answer was not required, the question is in fact a duplicate